# Correct date initially as factor in R

Tags: r

I have dates format like this `31.3.14` for example. I do:

```
 as.Date(gsub("\\.","-", "31.3.14"))
```

I get this: `"0031-03-14"`, what I would need is: `31-02-2014`

I would need that for random dates like: `31.3.99` (to get date as: `31-03-1999`)

So I don't know how I could just remove the `00` front of 31 and add `20` front of `20` to be `31-03-2014` and do the same also for dates like `31.3.99`.

Comment: Try `format(as.Date(c("31.3.14", "31.3.99"), "%d.%m.%y"), "%d-%m-%Y")`

Comment: super fast, great! So I can delete this entry :)

Comment: Well the post might be useful to someone else. Did it solve your problem?  I can post as an answer if you want.

Comment: yes, it solves the problem. I could not find anything similar so maybe you could post it as an answer. I would be glad to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping `as.Date` with `format`

```
x <- c("31.3.14", "31.3.99")
format(as.Date(x, "%d.%m.%y"), "%d-%m-%Y")
# [1] "31-03-2014" "31-03-1999"
```